Testing dependence of two categorical variables with data separated by test subject
This relates to a real-world experiment I'm working on. Let's say in my experiment, test subjects look at pictures of sunglasses that are either red or blue, and then label them "cool" or "uncool." I want to test whether subjects are more likely to label sunglasses of a certain color "cool."
My first inclination was aggregate all the data and run a chi-squared test for independence on the color-label contingency table, as such (with example numbers):




RED
BLUE




COOL
50
35


UNCOOL
45
45



However, this doesn't tell us if the judgments of individual subjects are affected by color. What if each individual subject is insignificantly biased, but in the aggregate these add up to a statistically significant bias? Or half of the subjects are significantly biased in one direction, the other half in another, and this cancels out in the aggregate? This feels like Simpson's paradox territory.
How do I rigorously test whether the subjects in my sample have their judgments affected by the color of the car?

Sounds like a random effects model might be the way to go.

You write "*What if some subjects just completed more trials than others? *". Does this imply that some subjects score more than 1 item, while others only scored 1? If so, your datapoints are no longer independent (1 subject likes blue, and scored 3 items, another likes red, but scored only 1 item). So your data is no longer representative of the population. Which would invalidate pretty much any analysis. Am I reading this wrong?

@jginestet I wasn't really thinking that through when I wrote it—good catch! I've checked my dataset, and that isn't a concern, so I edited my answer to get rid of that example, as I don't think it affects my larger point.

Can you elaborate on what bias means here?

@dimitriy intuitively, I'd mean that if $P(\text{cool},|,\text{red})$ is significantly different than $P(\text{cool})$ for a subject, then that subject is biased towards/away from red. Maybe "preference" is a better word for that.

I don't really know what it means for a subject to have a (conditional) probability of cool unless you view people as having transitory preferences, where they get up every day and draw a color preference from some distribution. Could you be describing the concept of ecological fallacy?

So, if we can assume that the datapoints are indeed independent, your first inclination of using a 2x2 contingency table (with $\chi^2$ or Fisher-exact) would work, and give you a valid result; it would tell you that, overall, subjects statistically significantly prefer one color, or not (you can reject that color does not affect "coolness").
Then you ask "How do I rigorously test whether the subjects in my sample have their judgments affected by the color of the car?". What are you trying to learn from that? That Jane prefers blue while Joe prefers red? Doing such an analysis subject by subject is pointless; it should be obvious that some subjects will strongly prefer one color, others strongly prefer the other, and some show no strong preference. But overall, as a population, there may be a preference.
Now, to be useful, such a "between subjects" comparisons should be based on different groups of subjects (e.g. gender, age, income group, etc... At least 2, or more groups). You can then keep using contingency tables (but now e.g. 2x4) to see if e.g. women and men have the same preferences, or not.
